# Parenting a .NET form to an HWND

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, winapi, c++-cli

I'm developing a plugin (C++/CLI DLL) that runs inside of an certain applications, about which I only know the HWND.  My plugin shows various .NET forms that I'd like to behave as children of the main application (e.g. centered to the main window, etc).  Here's what I've tried:

```
// MyDialog.h
public ref class MyDialog : public System::Windows::Forms::Form {
    public:
        MyDialog(const int parentHWND);

    private:
        IntPtr parent_;
};

// MyDialog.cpp
// Attempt1: Use SetParent and CenterParent
MyDialog::MyDialog(const int parentHWND) : parent_(parentHWND) {
    SetParent(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(this->Handle.ToPointer()), reinterpret_cast<HWND>(parent_.ToPointer()));

    this->StartPosition = FormStartPosition::CenterParent;
}
```

This appears to make MyDialog act as a child (i.e. you can't move it outside the main app, etc), but the call to CenterParent does not have the desired results.

I found several ideas online (including [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213661/can-i-get-the-behavior-of-setting-my-winforms-forms-owner-using-an-hwnd-native)) that suggest creating a NativeWindow from the HWND and passing it to Show():

```
// in MyDialog.h
void Show() new;

// MyDialog.cpp
// ...
void MyDialog::Show() {
    NativeWindow^ nw = gcnew NativeWindow();
    nw->AssignHandle(parent_);
    this->Show(nw);
}
```

However, this appears to, in all cases I can test, crash the main application (after showing my dialog, interestingly).  I will update the post with crash info if I can obtain it.

I am looking for suggestions on how to achieve the desired behavior consistently.  All I need is to be able to center a modeless dialog in the main window, and have it act as a child.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Kind of...looking at my notes, we traced it down to an issue with .NET's implementation of the FormStartPosition::CenterParent mode.  Instead, I'm using FormStartPosition::Manual and computing the position on screen using the parent's RECT.

Comment: I would post your solution as an answer if it resolved your problem. That way others can find it easily and vote on it.

Comment: I concur with your problem of the NativeWindow code crashing the parent app - in my case, the parent app is Excel and I'm passing it's HWND into my form. It crashes Excel on close.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue... If you overide the Form.OnLoad and do not call MyBase.OnLoad then StartPosition.CenterParent has no effect