# Embed WinForms form into Inno Setup wizard

Tags: c#, winforms, inno-setup

I need to embed a WinForms form (with `BorderStyle = None`)  into the Inno Setup Wizard and have an issue.

Here is an Inno Setup script:

```pascal
procedure EmbedConfiguratorForm(parentWnd: HWND);
  external 'EmbedConfiguratorForm@files:configurator.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  cfgPageHandle: HWND;
begin
  cfgPageHandle := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectDir, 
    'Configuration', 
    ExpandConstant(description)).Surface.Handle;
  EmbedConfiguratorForm(cfgPageHandle);
end;
```

Here is a C# code:

```
class WizardWindow : IWin32Window
{
    public WizardWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Handle = handle;
    }

    public WizardWindow(int handle) : this(new IntPtr(handle))
    {
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }
}

public static class MainClass
{
    [DllExport("EmbedConfiguratorForm", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static void EmbedConfiguratorForm(int parentWnd)
    {
        // System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        ConfiguratorForm form = new ConfiguratorForm();
        form.Show(new WizardWindow(parentWnd));
    }
}
```

It works but not as expected. After setup loads, it automatically call `EmbedConfiguratorForm` from `configurator.dll` and the form shows but not into setup wizard page. It shows behind (see screenshot).
So what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed a form from a DLL into an Inno Setup wizard page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795300/how-to-embed-a-form-from-a-dll-into-an-inno-setup-wizard-page)

Comment: Your solution is the same as in the duplicate question, except that they pass a parent handle to the DLL, while you pass a child handle from the DLL.

Comment: Sure. Remark is winforms form has no `Parent` as handle (`pointer`) but only `Form` or `Control`. So the easiest way is to use `SetParent` winapi function. I think this will be then same where You will call `SetParent` from InnoSetup or from DLL

Comment: You can use the `NativeWindow` to wrap handle, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/213751/850848

Comment: Have you try to use this (`NativeWindow`) by youself? Sorry but It not works in my issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved.

The solution is to return a handle of new window (form) from DLL and use `user32.SetParent` WinAPI function to force embed the form into the wizard. Here a piece of code.

C#:

```
namespace configurator
{
    class WizardWindow : IWin32Window
    {
        public WizardWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            Handle = handle;
        }

        public WizardWindow(int handle) : this(new IntPtr(handle))
        {
        }

        public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }
    }

    public static class MainClass
    {
        private static ConfiguratorForm _configuratorForm;

        [DllExport("EmbedConfiguratorForm", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static IntPtr EmbedConfiguratorForm(int parentWnd)
        {
            _configuratorForm = new ConfiguratorForm();
            _configuratorForm.Show(new WizardWindow(parentWnd));
            return _configuratorForm.Handle;

        }

        [DllExport("CloseConfiguratorForm", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static void CloseConfiguratorForm()
        {
            if (_configuratorForm != null)
            {
                _configuratorForm.Close();
                _configuratorForm.Dispose();
                _configuratorForm = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inno Setup script:

```pascal
[Code]
const
  description = 'my page description';

var
  configFile: string;
  configuratorPage: TWizardPage;

function EmbedConfiguratorForm(parentWnd: HWND): HWND;
external 'EmbedConfiguratorForm@files:configurator.dll stdcall';

procedure CloseConfiguratorForm();
external 'CloseConfiguratorForm@files:configurator.dll stdcall';

function SetParent(hWndChild, hWndNewParent: HWND): HWND;
external 'SetParent@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  configuratorPage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectDir, 
    'Title', 'Description');
end;

procedure ShowConfigurationStep();
var
  cfgPageHandle: HWND;
  cfgWinHandle: HWND;
begin
  cfgPageHandle := configuratorPage.Surface.Handle;
  cfgWinHandle := EmbedConfiguratorForm(cfgPageHandle);
  SetParent(cfgWinHandle, cfgPageHandle);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageId: Integer);
begin
  if (CurPageId = configuratorPage.ID) then
  begin
    ShowConfigurationStep();
  end else
  begin
    CloseConfiguratorForm(); // here we can make some optimization like checking previos page
  end;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  CloseConfiguratorForm();
end;
```

Note about C# DLL:
It uses `UnmanagedExports` NuGet packet (contains `DLLExportAttribute`).

Note about Inno Setup script:
In `InitializeWizard` function we need just create new page, but DLL call we need to implement into `CurPageChanged` to ensure our page is opened now.

---

After some research works I have created a little sample project explain Two-Way integration of .Net and InnoSetup

https://github.com/sharpcoder7/innoGlue.net